# Could not find class "..." Android 2.3

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having issues using this library on Android 2.3: https://github.com/ksoichiro/SimpleAlertDialog-for-Android

It works fine on Android > 2.3 but I get this error when I try to show a dialog on Android 2.3:

```
08-03 09:53:21.239: E/dalvikvm(2144): Could not find class 'com.simplealertdialog.SimpleAlertDialogFragment', referenced from method com.simplealertdialog.SimpleAlertDialogFragment$Builder.create
```

In order to use te library I've just imported it in Eclipse, flag the `is Library` and then set it as library of my project, do I need anything else in order to make it work for Android version prior or equal to 2.3?

**EDIT**

Right now i'm using it like this:

```
new SimpleAlertDialogFragment.Builder()
            .setTitle("test")
            .setMessage("test")
            .setPositiveButton("ok")
            .setRequestCode(1)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create().show(getFragmentManager(), "fragment");
```

What should I edit?

Comment: check whether library provides support for less than android 2.3

Comment: @KaranMer It provides support from api 4+

Comment: i guess its because fragments were introduced after android 2.3 you might need to add support jar for them externall\

Comment: you are using FragmentActivity or Activity. If you are using Activity then it works only 11+ version of android. To support below than 11 version us v4 support library FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Class is only supported on api level 11 and higher which means 
[Android 3.0.x  11  HONEYCOMB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

See the code of your requested class:

```
/**
 * Simple alert dialog fragment based on the normal {@code Activity}
 * for API level 11 and later which supports {@code Fragment}.<br/>
 * If you use android.support.v4 library,
 * use {@link com.simplealertdialog.SimpleAlertDialogSupportFragment} instead.
 *
 * @author Soichiro Kashima
 * @see com.simplealertdialog.SimpleAlertDialogSupportFragment
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class SimpleAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```

Also you can see on the [DialogFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) that
the DialogFragment was added on Honycomb.('*Added in API level 11'*)

To use the `DialogFragment` you must use a higher api version and if you want to use the support v4 lib use the `SimpleAlertDialogSupportFragment`.